# jquery mobile - loading function for every page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using a function to open then panel.  However, I see this is linked to the #index page specifically.  Is there a way to set it up so it's linked to all pages within my site.  I've tried adding data-role=page in a few different way after reading various posts, but to no avail.

```
/*Open panel on page load */
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){       
    $( "#menupanel" ).panel( "open");
})
```

tried

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageshow', function () {...
```

I think I'll also have the same problem having copied the code from http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/panel-swipe-open/#&ui-state=dialog

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#index", function() {
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#index", function( e ) {
        // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
        // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
        // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
        if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
            if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
                $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you want to run same functions on all pages?

Comment: This post looks a little familiar doesn't it @Omar ?? ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict JQM Panel to only 1 instance on page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634955/restrict-jqm-panel-to-only-1-instance-on-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bound to the index page because you are specifying it. Just remove that and bind to the "global" pageshow. Now every time the pageshow event fires anywhere in the document, your panel will open.

```
/*Open panel on page show*/
$(document).on('pageshow',function(){       
    $( "#menupanel" ).panel( "open");
});
```

This code:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#index", ...
```

...Is binding to the main index page's create event, which fires before pageshow, in fact, if fires before JQM has initialized the page. This example is to add swipe functionality for opening a panel.

Did you want that?

Also, just an FYI .delegate() has been replaced with .on() in jQuery:

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was because of the #index, just didn't know what to replace it with. Obviously nothing. That has worked, thank you.   Although, I still need to get more to grips with Ajax for this all to make more sense to me. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info on .delegate() - it was just something I found when trying to google an solution. I shall disregard it.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend looking at this thread and in particular the selected answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634955/restrict-jqm-panel-to-only-1-instance-on-page. I had a similar issue, and using just 'on' or 'one' on all pages resulted in the panel being loaded numerous times and slowing down the app/site. It was only on close inspection that I saw that a new instance of the panel was being loaded with every page navigated to.