# Restrict JQM Panel to only 1 instance on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a JQM theme using single pages. I also have a side bar / panel that is built as a seperate html file. This panel is imported into  the JQM page using the following JS;

```
/* Creates the functionality to open the left side panel with a swipe */
$(document).one("pagebeforecreate", function () {
  $.get('left-panel.html', function(data){ 
    $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(data);
    $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin(); // initialize panel
  }, "html");
});
```

Ive got this script in a js file that is loaded at the foot of every page, since users of the 'mobile site' could enter via any page.

Ive noticed via Firebug that an instance of the panel seems to be added with every page I navigate to. So if I visit 3 pages, the panel will be loaded 3 times, 4pages = 4 panels, etc.

It's fair to say I'm fairly novice at JQ & JQM, but I was under the impression that the use of

```
$(document).one
```

meant the event only occurred once per page, and would therefore prevent the issue I have.

IF you can help me work out how I can prevent this issue, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using separate html file, "_Single Page Model_?

Comment: Yup. 1 HTML file = 1 JQM page. The panel is also its own HTML file.

Comment: then you dont need to add above code to all pages in footer, just place it in `<head>`. Because `.one()` will be executed 4 times for 4 pages. You need to include it one time only. Your model is _Multi-Page_, all pages in 1 HTML file. _Single Page_, each page in a separate HTML file.

Comment: Ah ok, coz the header only gets loaded on the very first page accessed??

Comment: Exactly, `<head>` is loaded once, but when you add `.one()` many times, it runs many times. Let's assume that you have another `.one("pagebeforecreate"` that you execute different code in it, code will be executed in spite you have another `.one("pagebeforecreate"` somewhere else.

Comment: Ok so essentially the 'one' bit relates only to itself?

Comment: `pagbeforecreate` will fire ONCE per page, I've used `.one()` to capture first `pagebeforecreate` to run the code. check this, firebug it, you'll find two panels http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ee5pp/

Comment: An alternative approach is to inject panel on `mobileinit` which fires once per document/framework despite number of pages. `mobileinit` fires before loading jQM, inject a panel and then initialize it after loading jQM http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/PGv9t/

Comment: Ok cool that works. However, Ive got some other code in that js file that initiates an image lightbox. Is there anything I can wrap it in, to make it run only once the page has loaded?

Comment: there are many ways, 1) `mobileinit` as in my previous comment. 2) inside `pagebeforecreate` check whether panel is present in DOM `var panelDOM = $("[data-role=panel]").length;` if == `0` add panel, if > `0`, dont add it.

Comment: Cool thanks. As always.. THANKS!!

Comment: My pleasure :) here's 2nd approach http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yWE5h/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pagebeforecreate` event will emit on each and every *page*, but only ONCE. If you have 5 *pages* in one HTML file (Multi-Page Model), that event will fire 5 times *before* creating/showing the target page.

This event can't be *delegated* to a specific page, e.g. the below code won't work.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#pageX", function (event) {
  /* do something to pageX */
});
```

unlike `pagecreate` which can be *delegated* to a specific page.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageX", function (event) {
  /* use it to add listeners */
});
```

However, you can obtain an object of that page which is being created.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function (event) {
  var page = event.target.id;
  if ( page == "pageX") {
    /* do something to pageX */
  }
});
```

---

#### Why `.one()`?

Since `pagebeforecreate` can't be *delegated* and it fires on each page, using `.one()` will run code once only. However, if you repeat the same code using `.one()` that code will be executed it again.

#### Altenative approaches:

1. Check whether panel is added before adding it.

   ```
   $(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
       var panelDOM = $("[data-role=panel]").length;
       if (panelDOM === 0) {
           /* add panel */
       } else {
           /* nothing */
       }
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yWE5h/)**
2. Use `mobileinit` as it fires once per document/framework. This event fires before loading jQM, so you will need to *enhance*/_initialize_ panel after loading jQM.

   ```
   <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       /* inject panel */
       $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
           var panel = '<div>panel</div>';
           $("body").prepend(panel);
       });
   </script>
   <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       /* initialize it */
       $(function() {
           $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
       });
   </script>
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/PGv9t/)**

Comment: You can't do this your saying? $("#pageX").on("pagebeforecreate", function (event) { .... })

Comment: @red what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. In the top of the answer you say this: "This event can't be delegated to a specific page, e.g. the below code won't work." And you so your code. But can't we bind to a particular "pagebeforecreate" like this? $("#pageX").on("pagebeforecreate", function (event) { .... }). Thanks!

Comment: @Red2678 `$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#pageID", function ()` you need to delegate it.